# The development server returned response error code: 500 in react-native

Tags: react-native, error-code

I'm making react-native app with my frd. 
So I got the code my frd first made and I wanted to open my computer.
I think I set everything and did tcp:8081 setting in dev menu.
but I got error message after started react-native packager.
I use real phone device.

[image]

Please help me.

```
[2016-11-25 17:13:55] <START> Initializing Packager
[2016-11-25 17:13:55] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[2016-11-25 17:13:56] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (1172ms)
[2016-11-25 17:14:00] <START> Building Haste Map
[2016-11-25 17:14:01] <END>   Building Haste Map (668ms)
[2016-11-25 17:14:01] <END>   Initializing Packager (5738ms)
[2016-11-25 17:14:26] <START> Requesting bundle  url: /index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false
[2016-11-25 17:14:26] <START> Transforming modules
```

Comment: Can you show us your `index.android.js`?

Comment: `__DEV__ isn't defined`, the trick to close the working terminal won't work

Comment: Upload your index.android.js file here.

Comment: Link to github issues with possible solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3605 , https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7814#issuecomment-222975165

Answer (score 0):

1:- close the Terminal.
2:- close the application in a device.
And rebuild the application it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `react-native __dev__ not define` online brings back a lot of results and possible solutions.

Here is one which is quite popular:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7814#issuecomment-222975165
       *- enter 'babel-preset-react-native' in my package.json* - use this for reference:       https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native