# The development server returned response error code: 500 in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `react-native` framework for developing my android app. I want to use `react-native-material-design` library for making `Toolbar` with some more features.

I installed this library in current directory where my project is using below command :-

```
E:\>npm i react-native-material-design -g --save
C:\Users\ch-e00925\AppData\Roaming\npm
`-- react-native-material-design@0.3.7
  +-- react-native-material-design-styles@0.2.6  (git+https://github.com/react-n
ative-material-design/react-native-material-design-styles.git#bdc029c1a1c83ff563
d10868be38b8aed1e9989b)
  `-- react-native-vector-icons@2.1.0
    +-- lodash@4.17.4
    `-- yargs@4.8.1
      +-- cliui@3.2.0
      | +-- strip-ansi@3.0.1
      | | `-- ansi-regex@2.1.1
      | `-- wrap-ansi@2.1.0
      +-- decamelize@1.2.0
      +-- get-caller-file@1.0.2
      +-- lodash.assign@4.2.0
      +-- os-locale@1.4.0
      | `-- lcid@1.0.0
      |   `-- invert-kv@1.0.0
      +-- read-pkg-up@1.0.1
      | +-- find-up@1.1.2
      | | +-- path-exists@2.1.0
      | | `-- pinkie-promise@2.0.1
      | |   `-- pinkie@2.0.4
      | `-- read-pkg@1.1.0
      |   +-- load-json-file@1.1.0
      |   | +-- graceful-fs@4.1.11
      |   | +-- parse-json@2.2.0
      |   | | `-- error-ex@1.3.0
      |   | |   `-- is-arrayish@0.2.1
      |   | +-- pify@2.3.0
      |   | `-- strip-bom@2.0.0
      |   |   `-- is-utf8@0.2.1
      |   +-- normalize-package-data@2.3.5
      |   | +-- hosted-git-info@2.1.5
      |   | +-- is-builtin-module@1.0.0
      |   | | `-- builtin-modules@1.1.1
      |   | +-- semver@5.3.0
      |   | `-- validate-npm-package-license@3.0.1
      |   |   +-- spdx-correct@1.0.2
      |   |   | `-- spdx-license-ids@1.2.2
      |   |   `-- spdx-expression-parse@1.0.4
      |   `-- path-type@1.1.0
      +-- require-directory@2.1.1
      +-- require-main-filename@1.0.1
      +-- set-blocking@2.0.0
      +-- string-width@1.0.2
      | +-- code-point-at@1.1.0
      | `-- is-fullwidth-code-point@1.0.0
      |   `-- number-is-nan@1.0.1
      +-- which-module@1.0.0
      +-- window-size@0.2.0
      +-- y18n@3.2.1
      `-- yargs-parser@2.4.1
        `-- camelcase@3.0.0


E:\>
```

After this I am getting one issue while running a application, it is may be library was not installed successfully.

```
E:\Myntra>react-native start
Scanning 557 folders for symlinks in E:\Myntra\node_modules (114ms)
 ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐

 │  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │

 │                                                                            │

 │  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │

 │  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │

 │  prefer.                                                                   │

 │                                                                            │

 │  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │

 │                                                                            │

 └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   E:\Myntra

[01/23/2017, 13:36:07] <START> Initializing Packager
[01/23/2017, 13:36:08]         HMR Server listening on /hot

React packager ready.

[01/23/2017, 13:36:12] <START> Requesting bundle
                               bundle_url: /index.android.bundle?platform=androi
d&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false
[01/23/2017, 13:36:40] <START> Building Haste Map
[01/23/2017, 13:36:40] <END>   Building Haste Map (141ms)
[01/23/2017, 13:36:40] <END>   Initializing Packager (33314ms)
[01/23/2017, 13:36:40] <START> Transforming files
transformed 584/607 (96%)(node:6316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
 promise rejection (rejection id: 605): UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve
module react-native-material-design-styles from E:\Myntra\node_modules\react-nat
ive-material-design\lib\config.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in
 these directories:
  E:\Myntra\node_modules\react-native-material-design\node_modules
,   E:\Myntra\node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cac
he`.
[01/23/2017, 13:54:09] <START> Requesting bundle
                               bundle_url: /index.android.bundle?platform=androi
d&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false
```

PS : I am on Windows 7 machine, could not find a way to execute commands. I have seen this [The development server returned response error code: 500 in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40800516/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500-in-react-native?rq=1) but it did not help me.

How can this issue be resolved?

[image]

Comment: did you try installing `react-native-material-design` locally instead of globally?

Comment: @EmilioRodriguez yes it worked ThanksI want to know the reason how it is different if i install npm package globally ? and could you please answer this so that I can mark it accepted answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try installing `react-native-material-design` locally instead of globally.

It looks like react-native-material-design depends on react-native-material-design-styles which won't be packaged by React Native's bundler since its parent is a global module.

Comment: he was doing: `npm i react-native-material-design -g --save` instead he should be doing: `npm i react-native-material-design --save`

Comment: i have tried this but error didn't resolved

Answer (score 11):

`babel-preset-react-native` make this trouble. Run below orders in your project root dir:

$`yarn remove babel-preset-react-native`

$`yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0`

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue with port 8081, change it to 8082. because its already being used by some other service here is step its work for me

> > First run your package server:
> >     Blockquote

```
react-native start --port 8082
```

> > Open another command prompt, start the Android app as usual:

```
react-native run-android
```

> > Once it finishes, now rewrite the tcp port that adb tunnels:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8082
```

> > See the list of adb tcp tunnels:

```
adb reverse --list
```

> > Now You should now see a message like:

```
(reverse) tcp:8081 tcp:8082
```

check your app it will run ...........!

Comment: i have tried all the above mentioned steps but it doesn't worked for me

Answer (score 9):

- Go to your root project
- Open powershell
- Run `npm start —–reset-cache`
- When it is done, don't close it & open another powershell in your project's root directory at the same time
- Run `react-native run-android`

Comment: I have followed the above steps but it doesn't worked for me

Comment: This did work for me

Answer (score 7):

Sometime this error arise ***when you don't specify the correct path of*** `.js` files

Like instead of typing the **Correct** path :

```
var WeatherProject = require('./Main/WeatherProject');
```

A **Wrong** Path is typed (capitalization,spelling error,special symbols) :

```
var WeatherProject = require('./WeatherProject');
```

Comment: Thank You Indeed this was an issue.I capitalized my file name and forgot to change it in import statement

Comment: thanks i got your answer in my case in enter wrong images path.

Comment: Thank you, I went through all my files and realized I still had an import statement using a previous file I had recently deleted.

Comment: That was exactly the problem

Answer (score 3):

First execute, to get the version number:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>react-native -v react-native-cli
```

> 2.0.1 react-native: 0.56.0

Then I uninstalled react-native:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

> removed 41 packages in 3.999s

Then I installed react-native:

```
npm install react-native@0.55.4
```

Then I installed react-native-cli:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli@1.2.0
```

Then use this installation to create a react-native project:

```
react-native init --version="0.55.4" myprojectname
```

Comment: This solution doesn't helped me to fix the error

Answer (score 3):

As a newcomer to the React-native field, I used to face this error loads of times, and I always used to go confused. After a bit of experience though, I realized, it happens when the server tries to import something from a place which doesn't exist.

So checking what all you are importing and if that thing even exists, must be where you should start.

That means this error doesn't just pop up for an uninstalled package or so, but even if you are importing the wrong thing or from the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons why I was having this error was because I imported 'react-native' library twice.

```
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
```

I don't know If this can really cause this problem but removing the redundant line of import solved this issue for me.

Comment: i have tried this solution but it doesn't helped me

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, one of my node modules was not well configured (react navigation) so I just re install it locally using

```
npm install react-navigation --save
```

Comment: it doesn't helped me having same issue after trying this

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error is because of file path specified.

I got this error when i gave a wrong file path to the require function of image.

In my case, which was like

```
image: require('../assets/profile')
```

then changed to this solved my error,

```
image: require('./../assets/profile.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever any one get this kind of Error with  Error Code 500. Following reason behind this.

1) You might work in Linux system & You have to run application with the terminal & check into the Android Simulator rather in Devices.

2)If you work with above then please make sure your Simulator Wife should be off & then work with Studio It will work perfectly.

Hope you will get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

1) You might work in Linux system & You have to run application with the terminal & check into the Android Simulator rather in Devices.

2)If you work with above then please make sure your Simulator Wifi should be off & then work with Studio It will work perfectly.

3)Make sure there should be not open multi-pal terminal or command window for at same time. if it then close one

Comment: what's the point in copy paste other's answers?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with port 8081, change it to 8082.

react-native start --port 8082

Comment: This helped me with a similar error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the name of the JavaScript files that you imported is same with any React predefined libraries/components. For example, importing View.js from folder app/components that you have created.

```
import View from './app/components/View'
```

The above statement will produce the error. So, by changing the name of file to Interface.js

```
import Interface from './app/components/Interface'
```

Now, the code can run well

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-native version: 56.0 then downgrade it version 54 .Its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For those using `stores` or top level components. If you delete one, then make sure that it's not being imported anywhere else.

In my case, I deleted a store that was being imported top level.

Answer (score 0):

**react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res**

run this command : this will show the error like twice closing of tags or unable to find  any module

use sudo before the command in linux based systems

Answer (score 0):

For those using **stores** or top level components. If you delete one, then make sure that it's not being imported anywhere else.

In my case, I deleted a store that was being imported top level.

Answer (score 0):

**Same error. Different case.**

This error happened to me when i changed the "name" to lowercase in package.json file in Redux folder.

I did it inorder to fix the following error, which arises due to the npm convention, where they allow only lowercase `{ "message": "String does not match the pattern of \"^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$\".", }`

So inorder to fix the problem i changed
`{ "name": "Redux" }`
to

```
{
    "name": "redux"
}
```

and that's when the server error came. I changed it back to

```
{
    "name": "Redux"
}
```

and then it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is caused by "missing a module from nodes modules " always the prob is caused by @babel module solution

```
$yarn remove babel-preset-react-native
```

```
$yarn add babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0
```

view the issues on my github :https://github.com/HAFDIAHMED/red_gear9/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue and I tried to fix it nothing worked until I found the solution.
first you need to check what version of node js do you have and downgrade it.
Basically you need to download NVM(node version manager).
then follow the instructions on this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDScvojqAio