# How to resolve unique error when running React Native app?

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, react-native

I am using VS code with Android studio and I am receiving an error that I don't know how to resolve.
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0A4u.png)

I found out that My error is because I imported this into my app.
import headerTheme from '../../native-base-theme/components/Header';

How do I resolve this error?

This is what I am getting in my vscode terminal:

*info Reloading app...
[Wed Jan 06 2021 17:34:52.340]  BUNDLE  ./index.js
error: Error: Unable to resolve module `../../native-base-theme/components/Header` from `Components\layout\CustomHeader.js`:
None of these files exist:

- native-base-theme\components\Header(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- native-base-theme\components\Header\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
  at Object.resolve (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:267:42)
  at C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:434:31
  at Array.map ()
  at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
  at C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:275:33
  at Generator.next ()
  at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\shixi\OneDrive\Desktop\VS_code_files\NYUnity\src\mobile\NYUnity\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)*

Comment: There are literally thousands of questions and answers about this. Just make your research....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The development server returned response error code: 500 in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802749/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500-in-react-native)

Comment: I ran npm install native-base but the error is still there. I also tried running "npm install native-base-theme", but got an error. I updated my post with more detail about the error that I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be looking for the files in a directory two levels above in the file tree. The error returns ../../ in the file path. Can you either move those files or update the file path to reflect where the files are?