# Getting error code 500 when run react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

About few weeks ago my apps is running normally.
But today i'm getting this error.
[this is the error in android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBf0t.png)

[this is the metro bundler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrgrE.png)

[and this is my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjMEj.png)

I've spent hours and haven't come up with a solution.
I have tried reinstalling my react-native but the problem is still the same.
Can someone help me to fix this, especially the EISDIR error. Thanks before.

Comment: Refer this link your question is duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802749/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500-in-react-native

Comment: Hi Ignasius, it would be easier for us to help if you post code snippets instead of screenshots.