# error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile') react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im very new to react-native. Im setting up the environment for react native. I followed 3, 4 tutorials to setup react- native environment,but im getting this error.

`error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')` on the console

and

`the development server return error with 500` on my android device running android 11.

I've tried all the methods given in the following posts.

https://fantashit.com/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500/

[The development server returned response error code: 500 in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802749/the-development-server-returned-response-error-code-500-in-react-native/45722709)

[Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile') at Bundler.transformFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69647332/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-transformfile-at-bundler-transfo)

im working on this for more than 3 days, please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it will work.

Comment: tried didnt work